# Mutating trigger issue in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am facing mutating trigger error,

I will describe the issue here 
I am using tableA and tableB.

TableA holds a column called empChecked which can hold 2 values '-', '+'.
TableB holds a column called mgrChecked which can hold 2 values '-', '+'.

The current requirement is both fields in empChecked and mgrchecked must be in sync. i mean if empChecked is updated to '+' then mgr checked in tableB must be updated to '+' and vice versa. Updation is possible from front end for both fields.

I have created trigger on both the tables. but i am facing ora-04091 error.

Please suggest me any approach to achieve this?

Comment: Drop one of the columns because apparently they represent the same information.

Comment: that would otherwise result in infinite loop. Why not move this to domain layer and update both the tables in a single transaction?

Comment: @vicdor, I dont have access to business logic, as one is already existing screen. And other is created by me. so, i cant touch those table columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mutating table error is a code smell.  It almost always points to a bad data model, usually insufficient normalisation.

Certainly a bad data model is in evidence here.  You have a column on a table with two settings.  That's fine.  Now you want to add the same column to a second table and keep the two in sync.  This new column is completely pointless.  There is no information available in that new column than you cannot get from querying the first table.

And that's what ORA-04091 is telling you.  You can spend an awful lot of time building a workaround but that would all be wasted effort.

Comment: Code smell- I love it. I won't pass that on to my boss about why the project needs two hours contingency effort. Our scenario is different, an inserted row, then another trigger querying same table so we're creating a package to hold the row needing insert, and inserting it after row triggers are done.Someone says this will work..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using triggers for that kind of synchronization why don't you just create a view
named TableB that will "contain" all data from TableB (not mgrchecked) + empChecked column from TableA
Something like this

```
create or replace view TAbleB as
  select t1.id
       , t1.Column2
       , ... 
       , t1.ColumnN
       , t.empChecked
    from TableA t
       , TableB t1
   where t.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You're a little unclear on detail, but I think this would help (assuming you have an ID column on both tables)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_table_a
    AFTER UPDATE ON table_a
DECLARE
    hits NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO hits FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON (a.id=b.id) WHERE a.emp_checked<>b.mgr_checked;
    IF hits>0 THEN
        UPDATE table_b b SET mgr_checked=(SELECT emp_checked FROM table_a a WHERE a.id=b.id);
    END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TRIGGER tri_table_b
    AFTER UPDATE ON table_b
DECLARE
    hits NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO hits FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON (a.id=b.id) WHERE a.emp_checked<>b.mgr_checked;
    IF hits>0 THEN
        UPDATE table_a a SET emp_checked=(SELECT mgr_checked FROM table_b b WHERE a.id=b.id);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The key is don't use `FOR EACH ROW`, which will cause table lock.

---

**Edit**

- This will **NOT** conflicts with table lock or ORA-04091, because there's no `FOR EACH ROW` in trigger condition (a.k.a. not a *row trigger*), which means the trigger body will only be executed *AFTER* the whole update action has been finished;
- This will **NOT** cause an infinite loop, because when `count(*)` in trigger body returns 0, the `UPDATE` inside trigger body will not be executed;
- Also, `count(*)` has to be used because this is a *statement trigger* and there's no `:new.emp_checked` available;
- General scenario: Update table_a -> triggers tri_table_a -> [trigger]check count -> [trigger]update table_b ->triggers tri_table_b -> [trigger]check count -> done.
- I tried this out myself before posting this answer.

Comment: You're updating a table in this, which will cause a lock. You're also selecting from the table being triggered on... which is the original problem (nothing to do with locks).

Comment: @Ben I post **after** I try. In oracle, without `for each row`, trigger will execute **after** the whole action (`insert`,`update`,etc.) finishes, when table lock has been released. That's why I can't use `:new.checked` and stuffs and have to select `count` to check if I need to update.

Comment: @Ben Two actually. And despite the name "developer", to someone on this planet, not everything is ideally accessible. I know this is an ugly solution, but that doesn't mean no one should know it. I once have to build triggers and views and even dummy rows to just fit into table definitions that was created by others and that I can not change.