# Oracle trigger - from child table to parent

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that would aggregate values of a child table (after insert or update) to a parent table.
The child table `C` has fields `id, year, month, value`, and the parent `P` - `id, year, value`.
When a new row is inserted to C or an existing one updated, the trigger should sum all month values for that year, and write the sum to the corresponding row in `P` .
Here's how i implemented it :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER tr__aggregation 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON C
FOR each row 
DECLARE

BEGIN


 MERGE INTO P o
            USING (SELECT id, year, sum(value) as val
                  FROM C 
                   WHERE id = :NEW.id
                   AND year = :NEW.year
                   GROUP BY id, year) n 
            ON (n.id = o.id AND n.year = o.year)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (o.id, o.year, o.value) 
                                  VALUES (n.id, n.year, n.value)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.value = NVL(n.value, o.value);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    pck_util.pr_exception_info(TRUE);
    RAISE;
END;
```

For some reason i get this error : 
`SQL Error: ORA-04091: table C is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

I don't understand why, i'm not trying to modifiy `C`, only `P`.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mutating trigger issue in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346591/mutating-trigger-issue-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that you are **querying** the mutating table C.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025109):

> A mutating table is a table that is being modified by an UPDATE,
>   DELETE, or INSERT statement, or a table that might be updated by the
>   effects of a DELETE CASCADE constraint.
>
> The session that issued the triggering statement cannot query or
>   modify a mutating table.

You can read this [article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936) which shows how you can avoid the error.

Personally I would use a materialized view to store the aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you update P using a select from C which is just moving(mutating).

A better solution is to use a materialized view:

```
Create materialized view p
refresh fast on commit as
SELECT id, year, sum(value) as val
FROM C 
GROUP BY id, year;
```

I don't know the syntax by fly, maybe it needs some other clauses.

UPDATE: Just read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm#autoId13), you need also a materialized view log on base table, as in example 3:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON C WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
(id, year, value)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing that error `SQL Error: ORA-04091: table C is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` because you query `C` table `SELECT ... FROM C` while it's being modified `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON C`.  To get around that kind of error you simply can encapsulate trigger's logic in a procedure and execute it when needed. You also can create a view which is going to be a substitution for your `P` table.

```
Create or replace view P as
  select p.id
       , p.year
       , sum(nvl(c.value, 0)) value
    from P
    join C
      on (p.id = c.id and p.year = c.year)
   group by p.id
          , p.year
```